# How would you say, "open financial system"?

Tags: money

I've tried a few angles of how this could be represented, but they all feel clunky or implying other meaning.

*Iustus pecunia* was the first, focusing on justice and fairness

*Pecunia liber* seems promising driving toward liberty, but makes me feel *pecunia* might be too blunt.

I think *rebus oeconomicis liber* is the most literal translation, but I feel like I'm missing something here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the first question is how do you say financial system. Finance comes from the French *[finance](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/finance#English)*, which is related to the Latin *finis*. Still, there is not a native word for it in Latin. For finance, I have found two:

- *[fiscalis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fiscalis#Latin)*, which refers more directly to public finances, but seems to be used also for the private and general finance sector. For instance, in [this Enclyclical](http://w2.vatican.va/content/john-paul-ii/la/encyclicals/documents/hf_jp-ii_enc_30121987_sollicitudo-rei-socialis.html) by Pope John Paul II, he wrote:

> Systemati nummario et fiscali per orbem terrarum

which English translation (and the context of the phrase confirms anyway) is "[to] the world monetary and financial system".

- *res nummaria*, where *res* refers to things, and *[nummaria](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nummarius#Latin)* refers to money. Thus, *res nummaria* stands for "the monetary things". Is the word *res* also used in terms of system? Maybe there are some instances that is the case, but I don't know.

Regarding open, *liber* is an option, if by open you mean free. A free financial system might not exactly be an open one (e.g. it might be free market but only nationally), but in economics, particularly in trade, there is a close correspondence between a free market and a market which is open to trade, i.e. open to the rest of the world.

Thus, I would go for something like "*liberum systema nummarium*", or "*liberum systema fiscale*", or "*libera res nummaria*".

(I hope I'm getting the declensions right. Comments welcomed)